# Write text into a AbstractTableModel cell

Tags: java, jtable, cells

I have implemented an AbstractTableModel object which is a sort of timetable. I'd like to write into cells the subject that will be teached at that time **by using a method** (so I don't want to declare the rows as compiled yet).
How can I do? Here is my AbstractTableModel object.

```
private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columns = {"","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    private String[][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30","","","","","",""},
            {"9:30 - 10:30","","","","","",""},
            {"10:30 - 11:30","","","","","",""},
            {"11:30 - 12:30","","","","","",""},
            {"12:30 - 13:30","","","","","",""},
            {"13:30 - 14:30","","","","","",""},
            {"14:30 - 15:30","","","","","",""},
            {"15:30 - 16:30","","","","","",""},
            {"16:30 - 17:30","","","","","",""}};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

}
```

Comment: Any particular reason to not use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)?

Comment: yes, there is a reson. AbstractTableModel implements some methods (that you can see at the end of my code) which are very useful for my project. This is the principal reason. So I have to deal with this type of table

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` extends `AbstractTableModel`, so it has all the methods of the latter. (and implements all the features you need, as far as I can see).

Comment: yes, infact. MyTableModel uses the methods of an AbstractTableModel. How can I use these features you say?

Comment: For `DefaultTableModel`, just call the method; it implements the methods with the behaviour you expect (differs internally from yours, but the behaviour is that same). Any of the methods of `AbstractTableModel` can be called normally.

Comment: I'm not understanding.. What will you do in my situation?

Comment: Most likely it means that you don't need a custom table model at all, because the standard library provides one with the features you need.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But if you tell me "you're wrong", you will not help me. I know I'm not on the right way, infact I published this question.
So, what would you do in my situation? Can you give me even one code line, let me understanding?

Comment: I'm not telling you're wrong, just saying that there's likely an easier way. I'm not sure what you're asking. You can use `DefaultTableModel`'s [setValueAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method to set the subject at a specific slot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the [`setValueAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method.  You will also need to override the [`isCellEditable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) method if you want the table to edit the cells in question

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTable20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable20();
    }

    public TestTable20() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columns = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

        private String[][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"9:30 - 10:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"10:30 - 11:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"11:30 - 12:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"12:30 - 13:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"13:30 - 14:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"14:30 - 15:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"15:30 - 16:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
        {"16:30 - 17:30", "", "", "", "", "", ""}};

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            String[] row = data[rowIndex];
            row[columnIndex] = (String)aValue;
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've read `setValueAt` method. It is what I need. But I don't know how I can implement that. Infact if i copy and paste the interface of method on my table the method will be empty in its body. How can I override?